# How to correctly remove ubiquitous content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I have an iCloud-CoreData syncable application. And my goal now is to implement data wipe.
I'm using

```
+ (BOOL)removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:(NSURL *)storeURL 
                                               options:(NSDictionary *)options 
                                                 error:(NSError**)error
```

It works perfectly, removing all data from all peers, but the problem is that I can't start using ubiquitous container right after removing the content. It means that after

```
+ (BOOL)removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:(NSURL *)storeURL 
                                               options:(NSDictionary *)options 
                                                 error:(NSError**)error
```

is finished I initialise new core data stack. But none of new objects created in this new stack are sent to other peers. The sync is not working anymore.

Any assumptions what am I doing wrong?

Can anyone tell how to correctly reinit coredata stack right after `removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL` finished?

## Update:

Right before I call `removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL` I'm cleaning the core data stack with `[MagicalRecord cleanUp];` so that nothing retains the store while removing

Comment: you ever figure out how to correctly use `removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:` ?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the exact same problem between my Yosemite Mac app, and iOS8 app. Anytime I call `removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL` from the Mac app, the iOS app would never sync back with the reseted store. I tried deleting the iOS app, clearing the iCloud storage for that app in settings, restarting the OS X app, with no luck.

The only way I can cause it to re-sync: Have the iOS app invoke the 'removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL' method as well. After invoking this method on each device (Mac and iOS), and restarting them, the sync starts working again.

Steps:

1. Reset store from Mac app
2. Quit Mac app
3. Reset store from iOS app
4. Quit iOS app
5. Restart iOS app
6. Restart Mac app

Both apps sync correctly after that.

PS: Since this is not really an answer, but more a workaround, I could have added this as a comment, but do not have enough points for that. Still, it may be useful information.

Comment: looks like apple hasn't any working solution for this use-case.